# How to pass variable from template to ts in ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

How to pass variable from template to typescript from `*ngFor`.

I am using for loop as:

```
 <select (change)="onregionchange()" data-placeholder="Regions" class="form-control regions-select" id="regions" multiple>
    <option *ngFor="let region of all_regions" [value]="region.id">{{region.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to send countries for region selected to ts i.e. in region.countries in `onregionchange()`

How can I achieve this in `angular2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your function  `onregionchange()` you need to pass all the options. Like `change($event.target.options)`.

And in TS file you need to extract selected ones since you are getting all the variables in it. 
Something like :

```
onregionchange(countries) {
    this.selectedregions = Array.apply(null,countries)
      .filter(country => country.selected)
      .map(country=> country.value)
  }
```

Check this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/V4Oer0DPeYW1lSKuiOrx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you got a `onchange` handler on `select`. So, you can use that,

```
<select (change)="onregionchange()" data-placeholder="Regions" class="form-control regions-select" id="regions" multiple>
    <option *ngFor="let region of all_regions" [value]="region.id">{{region.name}}</option>
</select>

function onregionchange(e){
    console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

As you have given `region.id` as `option` value, you will get `region.id` of the selected option. I hope you can get `region.country` from that.